# Using EasyAr camera turned out of focus

Tags: augmented-reality

Dears,

I have a technical problem and i need your support.

I have tried my Augmented reality app on many devices ,but in 80% of devices CAMERA IS OUT OF FOCUS .

I have tried to attach CameraDeviceFrameSource to the main camera to adjust focus to make it autofocus or Macro .

but still facing the same problem , Camera shows blurry and out of focus.